# How to Accept integers from user and store it int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to accept list of primitive integer numbers from users one by one and store it to primitive array for later usage.
Here is my code:

```
     Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= scanner.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    int[] a = new int[arr.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = arr.iterator();
    if (n < 15){
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("enter "+i+" th number");
             arr.add(scanner.nextInt());
             a[i] = iterator.next().intValue();

        }} 
    else {
            System.out.println("Please enter number less than 15");
            //break;
        }e here
```

There is runtime error with code as follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at App.main(App.java:26)
```

I gues it is  failfast problem of ArrayList( not allowing modification of list while iterating over arraylist in this case).
How can I make the above code failsafe?....If I am right in understanding my problem?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `int[] a = new int[arr.size()]` should be `int[] a = new int[n]`; not sure why you also added a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You face this issue because you read the `ArrayList` thanks to the `iterator` and you modify it at the same time with `arr.add(scanner.nextInt());`. You should get rid of your `iterator` and use `arr.get(index)` to access to a given element of your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas,

Comment: arr.get(index) , works the way I wanted!! appreciated your immediate response!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add to a list and then read from a pre-existing iterator over that list.

If you want the element you just added, use

```
arr[i] = list.get(list.size() - 1);
```

However, `arr` has length zero, so `arr[i]` will yield an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should be sized to `n` elements, and you don't need a `List` or an `Iterator` to read from a `Scanner`. All you need is something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("enter " + i + " th number");
    a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: yes, that is also another way to go for it. Thank you.